# Get the height of the screen, not viewport

Tags: jquery

I looked for this and all I found is to get the height of the window.

Is there any way to get only the height of the browser screen?

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the bad English, I'm Spanish.

This is what im looking for:
[image]

The blue + red is the height of the window, I want to get the height only of the red portion.

Comment: I'm confused by the title/question

Comment: Edited with a better explanation @EdPitt

Answer (score 0):

Do yo mean the size of the body?

```
$('body').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> new document </title>
</head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script>
    var screenht = screen.height; //This gets the Monitors/Screens height
    var docht = $(document).height(); //This gets the view port height
    var toolbarht = screenht - docht; //You get the height occupied by browser toolbar
    alert('Toolbar Height: '+toolbarht);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for, but the problem is that it doesn't remove the toolbar height @lepanto